# Washing for bread with bandages covering the hands

Tags: blessing, netilat-yadayim-washing, bread, choleh-sick, chatzitzah

If someone has bandages completely covering both hands, what does he do before eating bread?

Normally with a bandage covering part of the hard, I've heard that you wash the rest, but in this case they completely cover both hands.

What about making the bracha of Al-Netilat-Yadayim?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One who has a bandage on his hand which is not easily removable should wash as much of his hand as possible (even if that amount zero) and take care that any skin which could not be washed not directly touch the bread.

Source: Shulchan Aruch [OC 162:10](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A1%D7%91#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.99), [Magen Avraham sk 18](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40431&st=&pgnum=226&hilite=), [Mishna Brurah sk 68 and particularly 69](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=114&hilite=)

It would seem that the appropriate blessing would only be said if some ritual washing is taking place.

Comment: So, if the person washes none of their hard do they make a bracha? I was wondering if they should cover the bandage with a plastic glove, and wash over that (since they will be using the glove to eat with).

Comment: @Ariel What would you be saying the bracha on?

Comment: On pouring water over the hand, even if it doesn't touch any skin.

Comment: @Ariel Why are pouring water over the covering on your hand? What mitzva is that that you would say a bracha on it?

Comment: Since the Mitzvah is M'drabanan, it didn't seem to be only about Tuma. Netilat Yadim just means to lift the hands.

Comment: @Ariel I don't think everyone agrees to that (it might mean _taking_ the kli/water). IAE even lifting has to do with Tumah: it's so the tamei water from your wrist doesn't roll back on to the hand and make the now-tahor water tamei.

Comment: So, what amount of skin needs to be washed in order to make a bracha? What about a small area by the wrist? Or the arm for that matter? I found lots of info about partial bandage, but nothing about complete.

Comment: @Ariel I'm not sure I follow the question: if any of the skin in the area that requires washing was washed then you would make a blessing on that washing. (This is borne out by MB sk 68 cited in my answer which shows how this is not considered Netilah leChatza'in but rather a full Netilah.)

Answer (score 1):

This would surely depend also on whether there is a specific medical reason that water should not touch the bandaged part. In any case, maybe bracha without shem and malchut would be preferable

Comment: +1 for "This would surely depend also on whether there is a specific medical reason that water should not touch the bandaged part", though a source for it would be most valuable.

Comment: @msh210 Are you _sure_? Did you see the Magen Avraham I quoted in my answer?

Comment: @DoubleAA, am I sure a source would be valuable? Yes. Am I sure that's the _halacha_? No: that's why a source would be valuable. `:-)` And, no, I didn't look up the _MA_, though now I will _bl"n_.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I checked _MB_ first (because you linked to it), and :68 says that the bandage must be irremovable _because of the wound_. Lemme check the _MA_.... [After some time:] He says similarly. While this isn't precisely requiring that water be unallowed to touch the wound, it's saying that there's a specific medical reason not to remove the bandage: so I guess this answer needs editing, but is not wholly off the mark.

Comment: @msh210 & Epicentre Could you clarify a bit? When you say "not to remove the bandage" / "water should not touch" are you implying that the halacha is different if the bandage can not be removed?

Comment: If the water could hinder healing of a wound (say a burn) and possibly lead to permanent damage or infection, then there could be room for leniency